# Ошибка IndexError: string index out of range в шифровальщике

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу шифровальщик на `python3.x` задумка такая: в каждом слове каждую букву на случайное количество. Программа выдает нам ключ по которому можно будет расшифровать послание. Возникает ошибка:

```
Введите сообщене:msg
m
Обработка1
s
Обработка2
g
Обработка3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ilia/1.py", line 41, in <module>
    a.encrypt(msg)
  File "/home/ilia/1.py", line 20, in encrypt
    letter = msg[index]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Код:

```py
import random


class Kriptograf:
    def __init__(self,msg) :
        self.msg = msg

#Зашифровать сообщение
#list(msg) - позволяет разбить сообщение по буквам
#len(list(msg)) - позволяет узнать количество символов в сообщение
#random.randint(0,33) - генерирует случайное число от 1 до 33
    def encrypt(msg):
        key=[]
        new_msg=[]
        alphabet = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
        index = 0
        while index<=len(list(msg)):
            rannd=random.randint(0,52)
            key.append(rannd)
            letter = msg[index]
            print(letter)
            alphabet.index(letter)
            alphabet[(alphabet.index('Z') + rannd) % len(alphabet)]
            new_msg.append(letter)
            index+=1
            print("Обработка" + str(index))
        print ("Зашифрованное сообщение:")
        print(new_msg)
        print('Коюч:')
        print(key)


    def decipher(msg):
        pass

msg = input("Введите сообщене:")
a = Kriptograf
a.encrypt(msg)
```

Comment: Нужно использовать исключения или перейти на цикл for

Comment: спасибо буду работать!

Comment: дело тут не в исключениях или циклах, а в ошибке

Comment: Должно быть строго меньше, а не меньше или равно `while index<=len(list(msg)):` ---> `while index<len(list(msg)):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

раз уж я тут, проведем небольшой `Code Review`:

1. нет никакого смысла вычислять длину строки как `len(list('string'))`, строка и так хранит в себе свою длинy - `len('string')`.
2. тут действительно было бы предпочтительнее использовать цикл `for`. не надо будет хранить индекс. и тем более его инкрементировать:

```py
for i in range(len('string')):
    i тут и будет вашим индексом.
```

3. старайтесь не занимать имена встроенных функций, вроде `index`, это плохой тон и уменьшает читабельность кода.
4. если функция находится в классе, она всегда принимает первым аргументом `self`. это даже не `best practise`, это канон языка. в вашем случае нет ошибки на этой почве, потому что вы не создаете экземпляр класса - `Kriptograf()`, вы записываете в переменную сам объект `Kriptograf` и от него вызываете функцию. если вы этого и хотите, сделайте метод статичным, иначе вы ломаете логику языка:

```py
@staticmethod
def function(arg):
    pass
```

5. ошибка сама тут довольно проста - вы проверяете индекс на меньше либо равенство длине сообщения, вот только индексация идет с `0`, и получается что на последней итерации вы берете индекс равный длине, что не возможно. исправьте на `index < len('string')`, а еще лучше воспользуйтесь пунктом `2`